# Using proxy(private) in PhantomJs with python

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I am using a private poxy IP with PhatomJS and Python, My code below

```
phantomjs_path = r"phantomjs.exe"
service_args = [
    '--proxy=MY Private IP',
    '--proxy-type=socks5',
    '--proxy-auth=username:password', # I enter real user name and pass here
    ]

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=phantomjs_path,service_args=service_args)
browser.get("Any website") # I use any website unblocked on that I.P
print(browser.page_source)
```

when I run the bot and I am trying to get the page source

But the output for any page is this why?

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

There is no error message shown I don't know what I have missed here?

Also tested with sleep function(I thought the page took some time to load)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port number needs to be added here,

```
service_args = [
'--proxy=MY Private IP:port',  # See the difference
'--proxy-type=socks5',
'--proxy-auth=username:password', # I enter real user name and pass here
]
```